# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jsp/_xxx wrong name: com/ibm/_jsp/_xxx

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, websphere-7

I have a problem that I can't figure out.

### Context :

- was 7.0.0.19 version (with no preCompileJsp)

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jsp/_xxx (wrong name: com/ibm/_jsp/_xxx)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:212)
>           at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.JSPExtensionClassLoader.defClass(JSPExtensionClassLoader.java:181)
>           at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.JSPExtensionClassLoader._loadClass(JSPExtensionClassLoader.java:133)

It's the only JSP that give problem, and only on a specific environment (no problem on the others environments with the same configuration)
the xxx.class is well present in my profile/tmp directory with others jsp in the same directory (that all give no problem) and the filesystem is not full.

### Tests

1. I did a copy of xxx.jsp to xxxNew.jsp in the same directory
2. I can access the xxxNew.jsp without any problem (so there is no coding problem)
3. So I did a mv from xxx.jsp to xxx1.jsp and had no problem to access the jsp new named
4. I deleted the xxx.class in the tmp directory
5. I did the mv back to the first name (xxx.jsp) and still get the error with a newly xxx.class in the tmp directory.

Is there a class cache anywhere in websphere that could explain this ? (no  cachespec.xml for dynacache found in the war module).

Why Websphere try to find a class from the org.apache.jsp package and not from com.ibm._jsp ? (how the AS choose the mapping from the URL to the classes ?)

Thxs !

Comment: did u find the root cause for this weird problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by redeploying (supress and deploy) the application.

Answer (score 0):

Is Websphere JRE selected ?

In Eclipse:

Right click on your project Properties->Jave Build Path -> Select the Libaries Tab. If no Websphere JRE entry is selected. Select the JRE System Libary entry and click edit than choose Wepshere JRE..

This solves my similar issue.. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thxs for your response, I'm on an AIX server and it use the default websphere JRE.